# How can i split single record into multiple records in ssis use script component

Tags: ssis

I have record like

```
pid  pname sal  Loc
1    A      300  hyd
```

I want output like

```
pid    pname    sal    loc
1       A       0       0
1       0       300     0
1       0       0       hyd
```

How can we do it in ssis

Comment: We need more information to go on. Please edit your question to describe the business logic required to take your sample input and transform it into your sample output. Also, please describe what you have done thus far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got the output you were looking for. Drag a script component onto the design surface and choose transformation. Make sure you connect your source component's output to this script component. On the Inputs and Outputs tab click on Output 0, in the Common Properties section you'll see a property called SynchronousInputId, change its value to None.
Now, in the Output 0, add Output Columns for each of the columns coming through the pipeline with appropriate data types i.e. pid, pname, sal and loc.

Then copy this C# code into main:

```
 #region Namespaces
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
 using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
 #endregion

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
    public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
    {
        public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
        {

            //Generate records for each pid
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                        Output0Buffer.pid = Row.pid;
                        Output0Buffer.pname = Row.pname;
                        Output0Buffer.sal = 0;
                        Output0Buffer.loc = "0";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                        Output0Buffer.pid = Row.pid;
                        Output0Buffer.pname = "0";
                        Output0Buffer.sal = Row.sal;
                        Output0Buffer.loc = "0";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                        Output0Buffer.pid = Row.pid;
                        Output0Buffer.pname = "0";
                        Output0Buffer.sal = 0;
                        Output0Buffer.loc = Row.loc;
                        break;

                }



            }


        }

    }
```

Make sure to build this code before closing out and saving.